# Identify partial text in the column and create new column in Azure Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a below text column called "Type" in my data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zweEa.png)

I wanted to find if column has Annual or Monthly and create new column called "Season". Season column should have Annual, Monthly or None

Expected Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhM5k.png)

I am using derived column but not sure how to extract the partial text in the column. Can anyone advise how to do this please?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following data flow expression in the derived column:

```
iif( contains(split(Type, ' '), #item == 'Annual'), 'Annual', 
  iif( contains(split(Type, ' '), #item == 'Monthly'), 'Monthly',
  'None'))
```

Explanation:

- [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#split) functions convert each row in *Type* column into array. (i.e. the "Founding Annual Member" will be converted to ["Founding Annual Member"] )
- [contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#contains) functions return *true* if the column contains the word *"Annual"* (first contains function), or *"Monthly"* (second contains function)
- [iif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#iif) functions evaluate the result of the contains() functions by returning the word *"Annual"* (iif in the first row), or *"Monthly"* (iif in the second row). If no matches found then the second iif() function returns the word *"None"*. (last row)

[Result in Data Factory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZXiT.png)

Comment: Thanks it's working. But I have one more condition to be added. some of the values has month. If I add this condition, I am not getting equation is correct -----------  iif( contains(split({Package Type}, ' '), #item == 'Annual'), 'Annual', 
  iif( contains(split({Package Type}, ' '), #item == 'Monthly'), 'Monthly',
  iif( contains(split({Package Type}, ' '), #item == 'Month'), 'Monthly',
  'None'))

Comment: Can you help @thomas Keul

Comment: @JasonW You need to add one more parentheses at the end of your expression like thyis: ...#item == 'Month'), 'Monthly', 'None'))) This is for closing your third iif function. Can you please upvote my answer.